# How can I export drawing from Notes to an image with background on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, graphics, notes.app

When I save drawing from the Notes app to Photos, the saved image has a transparent background instead of the background I see in the Notes app.

You can see the transparent background if you open the image in Google Photos or share the picture to any other app, e.g. opening that in the Preview app on macOS.

It is annoying when I share the image to some people and they couldn't see it clearly because of the transparent background.

Is there any way to export the drawing with the background (grids and lines) I've selected for the note?

Comment: @Domon, I also tried to make a drawing in notes, holding the picture until the tooltip showed and pressed save image. It had a white background, then exported to a photoshop app and the iMessage app and still saw the white background, even when tapping again to remove the bars on top. What does it look like for you? Can you edit your post with a screenshot of a drawing exported to photos?

Comment: @AnExistingPerson Use method 2 in my answer. you should receive PNG.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, oh didn't see your answer when I commented. But the image still has a white background for me; the only difference was the size of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

A third, more crude method, which you can use if a certain part of your doodle requires background lines/grids is taking  screenshot of the doodle.

Step 1;
Expand the note using the button in the top right of the screen.

Step 2;
Hide the panel showing pens and colors using the “x” at the bottom right of the panel.

Step 3;
Take a screenshot by pressing the home and power buttons at the same time.

Step 4; Crop the screenshot to show only the desired result.

The end result is something like this;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of saving a doodle in notes to Photos I have seen so far. First one saves the doodle as JPG and the latter as PNG. JPG would keep the background as the default white while PNG would render pixel-less areas.

**Method 1.** On the image, tap for some seconds and select share from the tooltip that appears. Tap save image.

Result:

[image]

**Method 2.** Use the share button in the top right and tap save image.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @ankiiiiiii, as you can see from your Method 2 screenshot, the background is transparent.

Comment: Method 1 does save the image with a white background, which is better. Thanks a lot.

However, if you change the background and save the image, the background will still be white. I really hope the app can save the image with the background I chose though.